Unable to install Caffe via Homebrew
Total noob, here. I'm trying to get OpenPose working on my Silicon MacBook Pro and understand that Caffe is a prerequisite, but I cannot get it to install in Terminal.
In trying to install it in Terminal I get the following error:
caffe has been disabled because it is deprecated upstream! It was disabled on 2023-10-17.
Any wisdom from the hive mind? Thanks very much in advance.
Yours,
T

As far as I can tell Caffe was deprecated in favour on Caffe2 and reached end-of-support in 2018. Caffe2 was also merged in to PyTorch back in March 2018! - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffe_(software)
